# Ubuntu 18.04 freezes when starting up MATLAB

Tags: 18.04, java, freeze, matlab, amd-ryzen

I recently installed MATLAB R2018b and experienced crashing on startup. Whenever I ran matlab from the terminal the splash would pop up for a few seconds, then the entire OS would freeze. I was forced to hard reset my computer as I was completely locked out. Because of this, no error messages or logs have been created at any point in time.

The problem seems similar to: https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/405904-matlab-crashes-on-startup-when-using-jvm-ubuntu-16-04-1?s_tid=mlc_ans_email_view#answer_362302. I can run MATLAB successfully if I start it with the -nojvm option.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: can you run `htop` (or just `top`) when you start matlab and monitor your systems resources?

Comment: Error messages in /var/log/syslog? Or crash files in /var/crash?

Comment: I ran with top, it used quite a lot of resources but that's normal for MATLAB at startup. I can't check the error files since the system completely hangs and I have to reset using the power button on my laptop.

Comment: Last lines in syslog are:

Feb 28 12:31:49 pepijn-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx rtkit-daemon[1191]: The canary thread is apparently starving. Taking action.
Feb 28 12:31:49 pepijn-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx rtkit-daemon[1191]: Demoting known real-time threads.
Feb 28 12:31:49 pepijn-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx rtkit-daemon[1191]: Successfully demoted thread 1603 of process 1601 (n/a).

And this looks like an error:

Feb 28 12:29:35 pepijn-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx kernel: [  732.131024] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 22s! [MATLAB:2835]

There are two crash files, I'll try to analyze them.

Comment: Unfortunately still not solved. Trying some things out with the MATLAB helpdesk seems to indicate this is a system issue related to Ryzen.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately still not solved. Trying some things out with the MATLAB helpdesk seems to indicate this is a system issue related to Ryzen. 
There seems to be known issues with Linux on various Ryzens:

- [Unable to install Ubuntu 18.04 on AMD Ryzen 2500U with Radeon Vega 8 Gfx](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1078568/unable-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-on-amd-ryzen-2500u-with-radeon-vega-8-gfx)
- http://kulminaator.blogspot.com/2018/06/linux-on-amd-ryzen-2500u-powered-laptop.html
- https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=196683
- https://community.amd.com/thread/225795

Other than that, there are many discussions on this soft lockup problem, none with a clear solution. Causes include graphics card, graphics driver, kernel, BIOS settings, power supply, etc.:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70377/bug-soft-lockup-cpu-stuck-for-x-seconds
- [NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for 23s! [plymouthd:305]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/875173/nmi-watchdog-bug-soft-lockup-cpu2-stuck-for-23s-plymouthd305)
- [NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for 23s! [nvidia-smi:566]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/929817/nmi-watchdog-bug-soft-lockup-cpu2-stuck-for-23s-nvidia-smi566)
- [Random freezes on Ubuntu 18.04 with error: "watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#11 stuck for 22s" followed by "NMI watchdog hard LOCKUP"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1087275/random-freezes-on-ubuntu-18-04-with-error-watchdog-bug-soft-lockup-cpu11)
- [Watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#4 stuck for 22s!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070661/watchdog-bug-soft-lockup-cpu4-stuck-for-22s)

Comment: Ran a graphics benchmark test to check if my GPU was working properly, and the performance is fine (score ~2000 in glmark2).